# Create radio buttons and check the one that has a value fetched from database

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a database from which I query the value of `gender` attribute. Based on that value I want to insert into a `jsp` webpage multiple radio buttons so that only the one that represents the fetched value is checked and the rest will remain unchecked.

```
<%
    while(rs.next())
    {
        String gender = "";
        gender = rs.getString("gender");

        if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Male"))
        {
            // What do I put here?
        }
        else
        {
            // What do I put here?
        }
    }
%>
```

I would also like to use `labels` with my radio buttons so that the final result would represent something similar to this:

```html
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="Male">
    Male
</label>
```

Comment: Simply give checked attribute to your radio button  i.e : `<input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="Male" checked>Male` else print normal radio .

Comment: no i want to fetch from database if in database gender value is male so in radio button will check tell me in that way

Comment: Try like this ->  `if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Male"))   { out.println("<input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="Male" checked>Male")  }  else {   out.println("<input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="Male" >Male")
        }`

Comment: thanks swati but it's says syntax error on tokens

Comment: This is because of `""` use `''` single quotes i.e: `out.println('//inputbox')` and see